# Indy UDP communications IP/Port confusion

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

This is difficult to explain.  I have written a RTP audio sender and a RTP Receiver which work well, written in Delphi using TIdUDPClient (sender) and TIdUDPServer (receiver). You can just think of these as sending and receiving data via UDP. These are encapsulated within 2 components that are used within larger apps.

The software containing the RTP Sender also has a separate UDP Server for accepting text commands.

In a separate app, which contains the RTP Receiver component, I need to activate the sender by sending a command to the separate UDP Server, eg. "startrtp".  Then in the Sender, I read the PeerIP and PeerPort and put these into the RTP Sender component and tell it to send the audio data back to the port that sent the "startrtp" command.  I want to use the same IP/port as I sent the command so any router at the receiving end will let this data through since it is expecting 2-way UDP communications, without having to do any port forwarding. I understand the port can be randomly generated by the router at the RTP Server end.  But in the receiver app, I'm not sure what port to set the RTP Receiver component to receive the audio data.

After sending "startrtp" to the RTP Sender app, would the sender need to send back a reply with the PeerIP and PeerPort details so I can feed that into the RTP Receiver component?  Or is there some way to discover this info from the UDPClient after sending the "startrtp" command?  I'm confused how 2-way comms even works over UDP.

I hope I make some sense.

One way of describing it is like handing over control of a 2-way UDP "connection" seemlessly to separate TIdUPDClient/TIdUPDServer components.  I know UDP is connectionless so surely this should be possible somehow.  I'm just totally confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then in the Sender, I read the PeerIP and PeerPort and put these into the RTP Sender component and tell it to **send the audio data back to the port that sent the "startrtp" command**. I want to use the same IP/port as I sent the command so any router at the receiving end will let this data through since it is expecting 2-way UDP communications, without having to do any port forwarding.

In order to do that, you will have to get rid of the `TIdUDPClient` on the Receiver end, and instead have its listening `TIdUDPServer` handle both text sending and audio receiving. You can send out the text commands using the same `TIdSocketHandle` object in the `TIdUDPServer.Bindings` collection that will be receiving the audio packets and firing the `TIdUDPServer.OnUDPRead` event.

If the RTP Sender needs to send a reply to the text command, then you will have to differentiate reply packets from audio packets in the `OnUDPRead` event.

Comment: I thought I had the answer as I did get it to work on the local network but not when the RTP sender was at a data center and receiver was here behind a router.  Does that mean the router doesn't support returning UDP traffic to the same computer that sent a UDP packet to the destination?  Not really an Indy question I guess.  Perhaps you have some experience.

Comment: On a side issue, to get the UDPServer binding to a port, I had to use UDPServer.Bindings.Add do
    Port := {a specific port}.  If I just set the DefaultPort to that port then I get an exception "Socket Error # 10014 Buffer fault" during the SendTo command.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Also, the Windows Firewall needed confirmation to add the application to the firewall when setting Active to True.  That's one reason I wanted to use a UDPClient rather than UDPServer to send the text command, but I assume that's not possible at all?

Comment: @Ross 1) check the router configuration, and ask on [sf]. 2) `DefaultPort` is used only if you set `Active=True` when `Bindings` is empty, it will do an `Add.Port=DefaultPort` for you. Please show your code that causes the 10014 error. 3) the firewall is reacting to you wanting to bind a listening port. You can try using `TIdUDPClient` instead but then you'll have to get rid of `TIdUDPServer` and read the incoming packets manually in your own timer/thread. You can't use two separate sockets on the same port.

Comment: 1) The problem is likely the wrong IP being used to send the RTP audio back to the client. The UDPServer being used to receive the "startrtp" command shows the Binding.IP as '0.0.0.0' in the OnUDPRead event. I need the actual IP the command was received on.  Is that possible?

Comment: If you bind a listening socket to `0.0.0.0`, it listens for packets on all local network interfaces. In that case, the only way to know which interface actually received a packet is to read the packet using the socket API `recvmsg()` instead of `recvfrom()` (`TIdUDPServer` uses `recvfrom()`). `recvmsg()` returns ancillary info about each packet, for instance `IP_ORIGINAL_ARRIVAL_IF` or `IP_PKTINFO` can report the IP/index of the receiving interface. Otherwise, if you have multiple interfaces, you can bind to individual interfaces as needed (the `Bindings` can hold multiple bindings at a time).

Comment: Actually, I found some code you posted for someone else which binds all interfaces via a TIdStackLocalAddressList loop.  This has provided the correct ABindings.IP. Unfortunately it is still not returning through the router.  I asked on superuser.com and responses suggested what I'm now doing should work. The router looks for the reverse details in the packet header with client_ip/port,server_ip/port being swapped for the return and being allowed through. I may need to do some investigation with wireshark if I can work out how.

Comment: Remy, ok, I have some news. As a quick test, in the UDPServer listening for text commands, I did a simple response using ABinding.SentTo(PeerIP,PeerPort,'Hello'), and this is coming back!  Once I send the Peer and Bound IP/Ports over to the RTPSender component (using UDPClient), this doesn't come through. So I assume there must be something else in the packet header that routers and firewalls use to match the outgoing & incoming packets before it lets it through. It's not just the IP and ports that need to match. Any idea about that?

Comment: Would the only solution be for the RTP Sender component to use a UDPServer instead, and have that respond to text messages, so it can send back using the same socket details. Unless there is some way to transfer the raw socket details to the UDPClient socket.